# How do I generate an Image through C# code?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I've got a button in my WinForms plugin. It's got an image on it. The thing is, when I click the button, I want the image to change from whatever image it is now, to whatever image I want it to be.

So basically how do i make button change its image? The image type is `System.Drawing.Image`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change a `Button`'s image in WinForms you set it's `Image` property. You can either load a bitmap from a file with `Bitmap.FromFile`, or you can draw an image using the `Graphic` class by creating a new instance of Bitmap using the Width/Height constructor (i.e. `new Bitmap(100, 100)`) and then use the `Graphic.FromImage` method. Lookup the documentation on the `Graphic` class for more info.

Comment: Thank you, did not know about `Bitmap.FromFile` at all!